# Landscape is missing on ubuntu 16.04.03

Tags: landscape, conjure-up

Landscape is missing on conjure-up version 2.3.1 which is the default on Ubuntu 16.04.03.

How to get landscape spell on Ubuntu 16.04.03 with conjure-up 2.3.1?

Answer (score 0):

To deploy Landscape server i would use Quickstart. It is super simple

https://help.landscape.canonical.com/

```
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

I have just deployed that on 16.04 LTS and it works fine. I also run 
`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

From my history on new Ubuntu server:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo add-apt-repository -u ppa:landscape/17.03
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install landscape-server-quickstart
```

Hope this will help
Thansk